# Symfony 4 : Get user object on logout handler give anonymous string

Tags: symfony, symfony4

i'm trying to remove the token property i have added in User Entity on logout listener but it's give me anonymous string. How can I get the User object to update it ?

**My LogoutListener:**

```
namespace App\Listener;

class LogoutListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called by the LogoutListener when a user has requested
     * to be logged out. Usually, you would unset session variables, or remove
     * cookies, etc.
     */
    public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        var_dump($token->getUser());die;

        /*$user->setToken(null);
        $user->setDateToken(null);
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();*/
    }
}
```

**My service.yml:**

```
    app.logout.listener:
        class: App\Listener\LogoutListener
```

**My security.yml:**

```
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern: ^/login
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                  check_path: /login

        logout:
            pattern: ^/logout
            anonymous: true
            logout:
                path: /logout
                handlers: [app.logout.listener]
                success_handler: app.logout.success.listener
```

Comment: Have you tried inject Security service? You can get the user there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistakes, I found the problem in my firewall config.
The login pattern was wrong.

I finally replace it by :

```
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            json_login:
                check_path: /login
            logout:
                path: /logout
                handlers: [app.logout.listener]
                success_handler: app.logout.success.listener
```

So, it's not necessary to inject the security service. The token->getUser() works.

Answer (score 0):

On symfony 4, You can inject the security service on your construct and the call the getUser method in order to get it.

```
public function __construct(Security $security)
{
    $this->security = $security;
}

public function logout()
{
    $user = $this->security->getUser();
}
```

Comment: It's give me null user. It seems that user is logged out before handling the logout function.